# Splitting a CSV into an object with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parsing, csv

I have an ordered array which looks like this:-

```
[-0.0020057306590257895, 50, 0.09598853868194843, 50, 0.19398280802292264, 49.99999999999999, 0.2919770773638969, 50]
```

What I would like to do is the following:

- Take each 'odd' entry and make it the 'key index in an object, which can be achieved by rounding the value and multiplying by 10 e.g. (Math.round(-0.0020057306590257895 * 10) should be index 0 and Math.round(0.09598853868194843 * 10) should be index 1 etc)
- Take the 'even' values and make them the corresponding values in the object.

So...

The above CSV file should return the following object:-

```
{
  0: 50,
  1: 50,
  2: 49.99999999999999,
  3: 50
}
```

Does anyone one know how I can parse this CSV to produce the required array using either jQuery or plain javascript?

Comment: where is your research effort?

Comment: I have tried using the javascript 'split' function without any success.  And so far every method I have seen uses this function. I'm certain I am missing something simple but string.split(',') results in a javscript error of .split is not a function everytime I try to use it. I'm sure this is simply down to me not having a good enough graps of plain javascript, therefore hoped that someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Some javascript terminology: `{}` is an "object" or "hash", these have key/value pairs. `[]` is an "array", it is just an ordered list, these do not have keys.

Comment: I guess the question should be how can I convert this into an object with the indexing that I require then.  My apologies for the poor terminology, this is due to my inexperience.

Comment: @gordyr No worries, since Javascript is loosely typed it's difficult to pick up what differences are meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding, there's nothing worse than feeling dumb when you are trying to learn something new. :-)

Comment: -1 removed due to your comment. Write that directly in your question next time, it helps providing a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've done something to read the CSV file into a string since you said in the comments you tried using `.split(",")`.

```
var csv = "-0.0020057306590257895, 50, 0.09598853868194843, 50, 0.19398280802292264, 49.99999999999999, 0.2919770773638969, 50";
var arr = csv.split(",");
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
    obj[Math.round(arr[i] * 10)] = arr[i + 1];
}
```

You should probably check that there are an even number of elements in the array first with something like `if (arr.length % 2 == 0)`.

The things you should walk away with are:

1. `{}` curly braces are used to define an object, a pair of empty braces means the same thing as `new Object()` but using the braces is recommended.
2. `[]` square brackets can be used define an array or address both the elements of an array by their index (like `arr[0]`) and the properties of an object by their key (like `obj['name']`).

Comment: Perfect... This is exactly what I needed, and actually far more simple than I imagined.  Thank you nwellcome for a clean and well articulated answer, as well as some good personal learnings. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = "-0.0020057306590257895, 50, 0.09598853868194843, 50, 0.19398280802292264, 49.99999999999999, 0.2919770773638969, 50".split(",");
var obj = {};

for (index = 0; index < arr.length - 1; index += 2) {
    var key = Math.round(parseFloat(arr[index]) * 10);
    var value = Math.round(parseFloat(arr[index + 1]) * 10);
    obj[key.toString()] = value.toString();
}
```

To get the value:

```
var keyVal = obj[key];
```

To delete a key value pair:

```
delete obj[key];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another good answer thank you Indikaf.... Unfortunately nwellcome beat you to it by a couple of minutes, and his solution did exactly what I needed (as does your incidentally.)  Thank you for taking the time to answer though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your data structure is guaranteed to have a value for each integer (i.e. won't jump from say 3.9 straight to 5.9 in the even columns) you can save a bit of effort and use

```
var arr = "-0.0020057306590257895, 50, 0.09598853868194843, 50, 0.19398280802292264, 49.99999999999999, 0.2919770773638969, 50".split(",");
var result = [];

for (index = 0; index < arr.length - 1; index += 2) {
    result.push(parseFloat(arr[index + 1]));
}
```

NB - this also has numbers rather than a strings as its values due to using parseFloat